# After closing the ssh terminal, the thin server is down

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails project run on the thin server(1.3.1) on a Ubuntu server. I connect with SSH to the server and start thin with command `thin start -C config/thin.yml`, following the `thin.yml`:

```
port: 3000
log: log/thin.log
timeout: 30
chdir: /home/byht/56platform/dev/tracker
environment: production
servers: 1
daemonize: true
```

After thin starts successfully, I visit the project and it works well. Then, **I close the terminal, I can also visit the pages that have been visited, but when I visit the pages that not been visited before closing ssh terminal, a "500" error appears on the page**. I didn't find the error messages in the log file.

I have tried start thin with `nohup` and `sudo`, but they are useless.

**I sign in the Ubuntu server locally, then the problem disappears.** But I need sign in the server to stat thin with `ssh` when I'm home.

Comment: Daemonize the `thin` instance with the `-d` option.

Comment: "daemonize: true" is the same as "-d"

Answer (score 1):

If you want a program to keep running after closing the terminal, than you can try `screen` to run a kind of virtual terminal that keeps active on the server, and can be used from another location at another time

```
screen
```

will enter this terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd> will detach it and

```
screen -r
```

will enable you to re-use it, with your program still running.